# S3 AWS Session Expired

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS S3. I did a lot of googling around how to connect S3 using python and found everyone is using Boto so its what I am using as the client. I used powershell to login and create the .aws/credentials . In that file, I was able to get the `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key` AND `aws_session_token` needed to establish the session. I understand that session is only about 8 hours so the next day when my python script runs to connect to S3 obviously the session is expired. How can i overcome this and how can I establish a new session daily? Below is my code.

```py
s3_client = boto3.client(
                "s3",
                aws_access_key_id=id_,
                aws_secret_access_key=secret,
                aws_session_token=token,
                region_name='r'
            )

# Test it on a service (yours may be different)
# s3 = session.resource('s3')

# Print out bucket names
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    # print(bucket.name)
    bucket = 'automated-reports' # already created on S3
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
all_active_scraper_counts_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
# s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
put_response = s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="all_active_scrapers.csv", Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

status = put_response.get("ResponseMetadata", {}).get("HTTPStatusCode")

if status == 200:
    print(f"Successful S3 put_object response. Status - {status}")
else:
    print(f"Unsuccessful S3 put_object response. Status - {status}")
```

Comment: You need a new set of tokens every a few hours. Don't hardcode it in the code. Get tokens dynamically.

Comment: I tried to run a powershell command saml2aws login -a to get a new credentials file and read from it. Is there some other way to get a dynamic token?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Run a script that updates the credentials before you run your Python script. You can use AWS CLI [sts assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) to get a new set of credentials.
2. Add a try/catch statement inside your code to handle credentials expired error. Then, generate new credentials and re-initialize the S3 client.
3. Instead of using a Role, use a User. ([IAM Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html)). User credentials can be valid forever. You won't need to update the credentials in this case.